# Can a non-segwit transaction be serialized in the segwit format?

Tags: segregated-witness, serialization

What would happen if a node sent a non-segwit transaction with flag and marker bytes announcing a witness section, but then put `0x00` for each input’s witness stack? Would this “waste of extra bytes” be acceptable to other nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended serialization format introduced in [BIP144](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki), which is used for serializing witnesses, specifies:

> If the witness is empty, the old serialization format must be used.

So, no, using the extended serialization format for a transaction with all empty witnesses would be incorrect.

Note that this is not a consensus or policy rule, but just a serialization rule. Violating it doesn't mean the transaction is invalid or non-standard, only that it was conveyed in an incorrect manner. It's a property of the protocol used between nodes, but in theory, two nodes could privately agree on a different protocol which has different serialization rules, as long as they use the normal protocol with normal nodes.

That said, the `wtxid` introduced in [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki) is defined as the double-SHA256 hash of the BIP144 serialization of the transaction. This aspect *is* a concensus rule, as the hash value is normative. Even hypothetical nodes that use a different serialization format must use the BIP144 serialization for `wtxid` computation. In particular, the combination implies that for non-segwit transactions the `txid` and `wtxid` are equal.

It is also the case that Bitcoin Core versions [0.14.x](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/8589) through [0.18.x](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/14039) unintentionally permitted using the extended format even for transactions without witnesses. This was just on deserialization; even if a transaction would be received this way, it would be serialized correctly on relay.